# Custom accessor name in Django multi-table inheritance

Tags: django, inheritance, django-models

In a Django [multi-table inheritance](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#multi-table-inheritance) scenario:

```
from django.db import models

class Place(models.Model):
    pass

class Restaurant(Place):
    pass
```

the subclass can be accessed through a superclass instance with the lower-case class name:

```
place = Place.objects.get(id=id)
restaurant = place.restaurant  # auto-generated from `Restaurant`
```

How can the accessor name be customized, such that:

```
restaurant = place.custom_accessor_name
```

?

Given that the accessor is an implicitly-created `OneToOneField`, it is not clear where the `related_name` can be customized. It seems possible to add:

```
custom_accessor_name = models.OneToOneField(Restaurant)
```

but it is not clear if such a field is redundant or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to define the one or one field manually, then use [`parent_link=True`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.OneToOneField.parent_link). Otherwise, an additional field will be created.

Comment: Good catch! I'll try to push a documentation patch mentioning this, because there's no clear link from the inheritance docs.

Comment: It is mentioned in the [multiple inheritance docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/db/models/#multi-table-inheritance) (see *specifying the parent link field*). However, if you think it can be improved, go for it and create a patch.